# UnboundLocalError: local variable ... referenced before assignment

Tags: python, error-handling

I get an `UnboundLocalError` because I use a template value inside an if statement which is not executed. What is the standard way to handle this situation?

```
class Test(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):      
        user = users.get_current_user()
        if user:
            greeting = ('Hello, ' + user.nickname())
        else:
            self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri))
...

        template_values = {"greeting": greeting,
                       }
```

**Error:**

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'greeting' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just do `greeting = None` (or a reasonable default) before the `if ... else` bit?

Comment: I don't know webapp, but I expect you want to do `return self.redirect...` anyway.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman: Sorry, I don't understand what `return self.redirect` does. Can you explain? I used `greeting=None` as suggested by Joe Kington and that works. Thanks.

Comment: It should say `return self.redirect(...` where it currently says `self.redirect(...`, because this causes `get` to stop running and give back the `self.redirect` result to the caller (first linked duplicate explains `return`). This is necessary because the rest of the code cannot run without a `greeting` value set (second linked duplicate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just Switch:

```
class Test(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def err_user_not_found(self):
        self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri))
    def get(self):      
        user = users.get_current_user()
        # error path
        if not user:
            self.err_user_not_found()
            return

        # happy path
        greeting = ('Hello, ' + user.nickname())
        ...
        template_values = {"greeting": greeting,}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used `greeting=None` for now; but when I am ready to deploy the app I may use this version. What does `return` do? Why is it necessary?

Comment: @Zeynel It exits from the routine, otherwise the interpreter will continue executing all the following statements.

Comment: The key point here is the `return`, which prevents the rest of the function from executing once the error has been detected and a redirect triggered. Everything else is just refactoring.

Answer (score 2):

I guess I need to explain the problem first: in creating template_values, you use a greeting variable. This variable will not be set if there is no user.

There isn't a standard way to handle this situation. Common approaches are:

```
1. make sure that the variable is initialized in every code path (in your case: including the else case)
2. initialize the variable to some reasonable default value at the beginning
3. return from the function in the code paths which cannot provide a value for the variable.
```

Like Daniel, I suspect that after the redirect call, you are not supposed to produce any output, anyway, so the corrected code might read

```
class Test(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):      
    user = users.get_current_user()
    if user:
        greeting = ('Hello, ' + user.nickname())
    else:
        self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri))
        return
...

    template_values = {"greeting": greeting,
                   }
```

Comment: Thanks. It seemed the second option is the easiest so I chose `greeting=None`. Why is `return` necessary?

Comment: self.redirect will only instruct webapp to send a redirect - it is a regular function and cannot really abort the execution of get() (except when it would raise an exception). So if you don't want to / must no perform any further action after the redirect, you really should return from the get right away, and avoid performing more activity (which then is either incorrect or unneeded).