# Python: UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I've got a piece of code here in Python Thread (Server) but when I run the client these error was found: "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'stop' referenced before assignment":

```
import threading
import msvcrt

stop = False
Buffer= 1024

class ChatServer(threading.Thread):
   def __init__(self,channel,addr,counter):
       self.channel = channel
       self.addr = addr
       self.counter = counter
       threading.Thread.__init__(self)
       self.start()

   def run(self):
       # press s to trigger
       if msvcrt.kbhit():
           if msvcrt.getch() == 's':
               stop = True
               print "Login is closed closed.\n"
       while 1:
           if (stop == False):
               print "\nClient connection received!\n"
               self.channel.send("Status: Server connection received")

counter = 0                   
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(("",500))
server.listen(20)

while True:
    print "\nServer awaiting connections....\n"
    channel, addr = server.accept()
    counter += 1
    ChatServer(channel,addr,counter)
```

Comment: a duplicate of oh-so-many [others](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+UnboundLocalError%3A+local+variable+referenced+before+assignment)...

Comment: possible duplicate of [UnboundLocalError: local variable ... referenced before assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048745/unboundlocalerror-local-variable-referenced-before-assignment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only set the variable `stop` under very specific conditions and never set it to `False`. Add an explicit `stop = False` to the top of the `run()` function.

```
def run(self):
   stop = False
   # press s to trigger
   if msvcrt.kbhit():
       if msvcrt.getch() == 's':
           stop = True
           print "Login is closed closed.\n"
   while 1:
       if (stop == False):
           print "\nClient connection received!\n"
           self.channel.send("Status: Server connection received")
```

You *probably* want to set `stop` *inside* the `while` loop at some point, as it stands it'll never stop if `stop = True` is reached.

Comment: is stop = False is not enough as I declared it on the top? if I add stop = False to the top of the run() function the stop will never have a false value?

Comment: @Kit: If `msvcrt.kbhit()` is True and `msvcrt.getch()` is equal to `'s'`, then `stop` is set to `True`; your `while 1` loop then will *never* see the local variable `stop` become `False`, because there is nothing inside of the loop that changes it's value.

Comment: @Wooble: thanks for that fix, I had to attend to something else for a few minutes and the formatting error slipped through.

Comment: I have another concern here Sir, Im expecting the code to just show 1  print because when I run the code, the message Client connection received! print many times, and also I want the value to be the same with the other open clients so other clients cant login also once I pressed 's' key

Comment: @Kit: Your loop prints over and over again, because it is an infinite loop. You need to *alter* that loop to check for the stop event. How you do that with the other clients is up to you. I can help you with the `UnboundLocal` exception, and some general tips, but nothing more.