# Referencing before assignment error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting the error "local variable 'Xold' referenced before assignment". I don't understand why I am getting the error as I have assigned the variable in question before I attempt use it.

```
def calculator (newX,newY):
    global count
    if  count==0:
        Xold = newX
        Yold = newY
        count+=1
        print(Xold,Yold) #prints 97.9 which is correct. 
    else:
        Xdistance = newX - Xold
        Ydistance = newY - Yold
        print(Xdistance,Ydistance)
        parser()
```

Just to mention, count is set to 0 at the beginning of the code.

Comment: Yes, if you enter the else block neither `Xold` not a Yold` are defined. So it will give this error any time `count != 0`

Comment: Hint: All of the variables in a function are thrown away as soon as the function returns (or when execution "falls off the end" of the function).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnboundLocalError: local variable ... referenced before assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048745/unboundlocalerror-local-variable-referenced-before-assignment)

Comment: The issue is that `Xold` and `Yold` are local, not global, so even if `count` is then, once it is > 0, the error will rise

Comment: @Kevin so I need to store the variable elsewhere? I just want to have the initial value from the parser stored in Xold and Yold.

Answer (score 2):

Your `else` guard is executing first, so `Xold` is not being assigned. Even though Xold appears in a line above, it's in a block that isn't being executed.

The steps as they are executed are:

```
calculator(x, y)
  if count == 0 # False
  else:
  Xdistance = newX - Xold # Xold is not defined yet
```

You will need to define it with sensible variables outside the if clause.

If you want to be clever, you can do something like this

```
count = 0

def calculator (newX,newY):
    global count
    if  count==0:
        calculator.Xold = newX
        calculator.Yold = newY
    count+=1
    print(calculator.Xold,calculator.Yold) #prints 97.9 which is correct. 
else:
    ...
```